# How do I set all values to be horizontal in plotly piechart?

Tags: python, plotly, pie-chart

I created this piechart with plotly: [image]

Anyone knows a smart command that all the shares are horizontal?

i.e. set the percentage values of  Planing/scheduling and Robotics horizontal.

Or if the above is not possible, format the two categories the same way as the smallest catgories (Biometrics, Char Recognition,...)?

I tried it with decreasing fontsize, but there must be a smarter method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `insidetextorientation="horizontal"`? See "Controlling text orientation inside pie sectors" in the Plotly documentation: https://plotly.com/python/pie-charts/#controlling-text-orientation-inside-pie-sectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As gflavia suggested, the insidetextorientation helps with the problem .

Setting

```
fig.update_traces(insidetextorientation='horizontal')
```

formats the piechart as intended: [image]